# Why fread reads bytes in a file altough I don't indicate what byte is next to read?

Tags: c

I have this code that copy a file in a destination

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    FILE *input = fopen("input.txt", "r");
    if (input == NULL)
    {
        return 1;
    }

    FILE *output = fopen("output.txt", "w");
    if (output == NULL)
    {
        fclose(input);
        return 1;
    }

    char c;
    while (fread(&c, sizeof(char), 1, input))
    {
        fwrite(&c, sizeof(char), 1, output);
    }

    fclose(input);
    fclose(output);
}
```

The program works but i don't understand how, in the while loop, fread/fwrite can know what is the next byte to use without I say it.

Comment: There is state stored in the `FILE *`. Specifically the file position is in there.

Comment: ... and the file-position gets automatically increased by the number of bytes read/written during each fread()/fwrite() call.

Comment: " fread/fwrite can know what is the next byte to use without I say it." --> code does _say_ by providing a buffer `&c` to store the byte.

Comment: Each time you read 1-byte, the *file-position-indicator* is advanced (moved forward in the file) by 1-byte so it is automatically ready to read the next character. When you write, you are appending to the end of the file -- which will always know where to write the next character.